# Deleting `CMakeCache.txt` causes `OPTIONAL` install targets to no longer be built

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ninja

I'm seeing a weird build problem that may be somewhat difficult to reproduce. I'm using CMake with Ninja to build a C++ project that uses Qt 5.5. I *think* the only relevant part of this concoction is CMake itself, but Qt definitely adds some wrinkles to the build system, so that's a possible culprit as well.

Here's the chain of events that led to my problem:

1. I added a virtual method declaration to a base class, but forgot to make it pure virtual (`=0`). I implemented the method in the derived classes, but got an `undefined reference to vtable` link error due to the lack of a base-class implementation.

   1. One of the derived classes *also* inherits from `QObject` and is therefore subject to `automoc`. I don't believe this is related to the build issue.
2. At some point while I was trying to figure out why I was getting a link error, I deleted my `CMakeCache.txt` file.

   1. I also deleted the entire parent directory of the build directory containing the virtual and derived classes in question. I'm not sure if this is part of the problem or not.
3. I realized I needed to make the base-class method pure-virtual, and successfully completed my build.
4. **PROBLEM:** `ninja install` no longer installs *any* of my binary targets (all of which are declared `OPTIONAL` to permit partial build/install of the project for quick iteration), even after re-running `CMake` several times.

I re-deleted `CMakeCache.txt` and re-ran CMake and `ninja`, but I couldn't get the targets to be re-installed until I completely deleted my build directory.

One of my co-workers has also run into this issue, although I don't know how (he may have deleted or otherwise corrupted his `CMakeCache.txt` file, but he doesn't actually remember what he was doing immediately prior to seeing the problem).

**EDIT:** I'm having this problem again, and it appears that when I make targets non-`OPTIONAL`, CMake expects to find them in various subdirectories of the `CMakeFiles` directories (in the build-artifacts tree) called `CMakeRelink.dir`. This directory apparently never exists. Even setting `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY` to `false` and re-running CMake doesn't appear to resolve the issue, which makes no sense to me.

**EDIT 2:** I *think* this is the same bug, and there are a few workarounds: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13934

Comment: If you think this is a **bug**, you should report it on CMake(or ninja) bugzilla, not here. Actually, removing only `CMakeCache,txt` doesn't always safe, but I agree that situation with installed directives lost looks weird. In any case,removing whole build tree cures that, as usual.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm still open to the idea that it's user error. Even if it's a bug, I'd like to have more information about what causes it before reporting it.

Comment: Also, if anyone knows of a way to fix this without re-doing the entire build, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be due to a bug in how CMake handles its post-processing for binaries. By default, the `install` command strips embedded library-paths from binaries before installing them. For ELF binaries, CMake has some kind of built-in path-stripper that actually reads the ELF file and creates a new file without the embedded path; for non-ELF file, a different scheme is used. Notably, **CMake uses different files for the unstripped binaries depending on which scheme will be used to strip them.** I have no idea why this is, but it's the underlying cause of the build error.

Without `CMakeCache.txt`, CMake appears to "forget" which scheme was used (or should be used) to strip the files. Thus, it looks for the unstripped binaries in the wrong artifact directory.

This is a [known (though somewhat obscure) CMake bug](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=13934); the simplest workaround is to explicitly specify (when appropriate) that target binaries are in ELF format by setting the `CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT` variable.